# How can I create a view that retrieves all objects with matching primary key in url?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models that form a one-to-many relationship. One pallet has multiple images associated with it.

## models.py

```
class Pallet(models.Model):

    pallet_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pallet_id)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('pallet_id',)


class Image(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pallet = models.ForeignKey(Pallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.created)
```

I'm trying to create a view where I get all images associated with a particular pallet_id from the url.

## serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    pallet = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'

class PalletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pallet
        fields = '__all__'
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^pallets/', include([
        url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PalletDetail.as_view(), name='pallet-detail'),
        ])),
]
```

I think the issue is in the views.py with the PalletDetail class. I am confused on how to write the view based on the primary key from the URL. I've tried to use **kwargs['pk'] but does using this make it a function-based view? If so, would it be bad form to mix class-based and function-based views? How can I get similar behavior from class-based views?

I'm really struggling with the views here:

## views.py

```
class PalletDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.prefetch_related('pallet').all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Function based view** 
pass pk parameter 
**example:**

```
def Example_function(request, pk):
    queryset = Model.objects.filter(id=pk)
```

**In Class-Based views**
get url parameter

```
pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
queryset = Model.objects.filter(id=pk)
```

Comment: Are there any arguments for `Model.objects.all()`? I can't find it on the [queryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/); I got `TypeError: all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'` when I tried it

Comment: use *`filter()`*

Comment: How did you pass in id?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake use `filter(id=pk)`

Comment: In CBV this is not the correct way... have a look here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/09/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-6.html

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it the wrong way. You want to return a list of images belonging to the pallet so what you need is a list view for the images and not a pallet detail view. The url should look like this:

```
/pallets/<pallet_id>/images/
```

In this way the url is self-descriptive and by REST standards you can easily see that you are requesting for images belonging to a pallet and not the pallet itself

In **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^pallets/', include([
        url(r'^(?P<pallet_pk>[0-9]+)/images/$', views.PalletImagesListView.as_view(), name='pallet-images-list'),
        ])),
]
```

In views, you have to overide the `get_queryset()` method, so that it only returns the images for the pallet specified

```
class PalletImagesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Image.objects.prefetch_related('pallet').filter(pallet__pk=self.kwargs.get('pallet_pk'))
```

So now you can request the first pallet's images with `/pallets/1/images/`

Comment: That's so great! Can I make it request the images of a particular pallet_id? pallet_id is the primary_key for Pallet

Comment: For some reason, when I try running this, the view doesn't differ from the PalletList view. I'm super confused why this is happening...

Comment: It defers. Your palletlist view should return a list of pallets while this view returns a list of images belonging to a specified pallet

Comment: As I already showed in the last sentence, the `pallet_pk` is the id of the pallet and you should request the images for a pallet by inserting the id of the pallet in the url like `/pallets/1/images/` for pallet with id 1

Answer (score 0):

You are using the serializer and view in a wrong way.

The problem with yours `PalletDetail` view is that you are using the wrong queryset. The queryset should return `Pallet` objects, since the lookup will be on that queryset (default lookup field is 'pk'). Also, you will then need to use the serializer for `Pallet` since that is supposed to handle the data for the `Pallet` object.

```
class PalletDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Pallet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PalletSerializer
```

Comment: How do I find all images associated with the `pallet_id`? I already have a Pallet List view like that ```class PalletList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Pallet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PalletSerializer```

Comment: List view will give you all the `Pallet` items along with their details. `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` works only on one object which, in you case, will be retrieved by the 'pk' field in url.
Check the data returned by the API after the above updates.
If you want to show more data, you can use always update your serializer class, but it will always be for the parent object. [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filter_by() method

```
queryset = Model.query.filter_by(id=pk).first()
```